# How to add a new set of images in ng carousel and go to the next slide at the same time?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I'm working in an Angular 7 project and everything is running fine, except for this: I have a set of images in a ngb-carousel. After clicking a button a function is triggered and it load a new set (Array) of images in the same carousel. So, I would like to visualize the first image of the new set of images.

For example, if I have 5 images (0,1,2,3,4) and I click the button to add 5 more (5,6,7,8,9) I want it to show me the image number 5  in the new set (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), i.e. the first image of the second set. All in the same function.

I load slides with ngfor so there is a variable that contains them. So I refresh this variable with the new set of images. It looks like the next() function is executed before the carousel is refreshed.

In HTML:

```
 <ngb-carousel #myCarousel = "ngbCarousel" >
        <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let img of carrete; let i=index" id= "{{i}}">
            <img src="{{img}}" id = {{i}}_img >
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>Imagen {{i}}</p>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-carousel>
```

in Typescript:

```
cargarCarrete(nuevo: Array<string>){
    this.carrete=this.carrete.concat(nuevo);
    this.myCarousel.next();
}
```

Comment: can you share a your code which is done by you so far

Comment: I just edited my question